# How to sort Javascript objects in an array using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I'm making a call to an API and getting an array with large amounts of objects. There are hundreds of objects in the array and a short snippet of it looks something like this:

```
[
    {
      "name": "total_kills_glock",
      "value": 70
    },
    {
      "name": "total_kills_mac10",
      "value": 39
    },
    {
      "name": "total_kills_ump45",
      "value": 136
    },
    {
      "name": "total_shots_glock",
      "value": 1262
    },
    {
      "name": "total_hits_glock",
      "value": 361
    }
    {
      "name": "total_shots_mac10",
      "value": 862
    },
    {
      "name": "total_hits_mac10",
      "value": 261
    },
    {
      "name": "total_shots_ump45",
      "value": 1610
    },
    {
      "name": "total_hits_ump45",
      "value": 598
    }
]
```

Is there a way to sort the array using regex to look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "glock",
    "kills": 70,
    "shots": 1262,
    "hits": 361
  },
  {
    "name": "mac10",
    "kills": 39,
    "shots": 862,
    "hits": 261
  },
  {
    "name": "ump45",
    "kills": 136,
    "shots": 1610,
    "hits": 598
  }
]
```

Comment: You should try it first and share your code instead of directly stating requirements. I don’t see an attempt made to solve this.

Comment: Ah, that is my bad, I didn't put the code that I've created so far. I only post when I know I tried working on a solution for hours and still can't come up with an answer.

Comment: @Leon kindly check my answer out https://stackoverflow.com/a/58254128/12167785

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using regex to extract the name and data type from the raw name, and then building an object based on that:

```js
const raw = [{
    "name": "total_kills_glock",
    "value": 70
  },
  {
    "name": "total_kills_mac10",
    "value": 39
  },
  {
    "name": "total_kills_ump45",
    "value": 136
  },
  {
    "name": "total_shots_glock",
    "value": 1262
  },
  {
    "name": "total_hits_glock",
    "value": 361
  },
  {
    "name": "total_shots_mac10",
    "value": 862
  },
  {
    "name": "total_hits_mac10",
    "value": 261
  },
  {
    "name": "total_shots_ump45",
    "value": 1610
  },
  {
    "name": "total_hits_ump45",
    "value": 598
  }
];

var final = [];
var keys = [];
raw.forEach(v => {
  const m = v.name.match(/^total_([^_]+)_(.+)$/);
  const k = keys.indexOf(m[2]);
  if (k == -1) {
    var o = { name: m[2] };
    o[m[1]] = v.value;
    final.push(o);
    keys.push(m[2]);
  } else {
    final[k][m[1]] = v.value;
  }
});
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to group the array items, [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to extract name and action from `name` string.

```js
var data = [{ "name": "total_kills_glock", "value": 70 }, { "name": "total_kills_mac10", "value": 39 }, { "name": "total_kills_ump45", "value": 136 }, { "name": "total_shots_glock", "value": 1262 }, { "name": "total_hits_glock", "value": 361 }, { "name": "total_shots_mac10", "value": 862 }, { "name": "total_hits_mac10", "value": 261 }, { "name": "total_shots_ump45", "value": 1610 }, { "name": "total_hits_ump45", "value": 598 } ];

var result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let words = curr.name.split('_');
  let name = words[2];
  let action = words[1];

  let item = acc.find(item => item.name === name);

  if (item) {
    item[action] = curr.value;
  } else {
    acc.push({
      "name": name,
      [action]: curr.value
    });
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's works really well! I thought that the only solution would be to use regex, but I was wrong. I'm going to apply this to other parts of my application.

Comment: That's nice to hear @Leon. Regex of course works, but [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) would be enough and suits perfectly for this simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check this out.

```
let arr=[] //your array
let map=new Map();
arr.forEach((obj)=>{
let x=obj.name.split('_');
map.set(x[2],{"name":x[2],...map.get(x[2]),[x[1]]:obj.value})
}
);
console.log([...map.values()]);
```

Feel free to use my repl https://repl.it/repls/PoisedEasyZettabyte in case you want it.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string and destructure the items and take an object as hash table for the same group. At the end take the values from the hash table.

```js
var data = [{ name: "total_kills_glock", value: 70 }, { name: "total_kills_mac10", value: 39 }, { name: "total_kills_ump45", value: 136 }, { name: "total_shots_glock", value: 1262 }, { name: "total_hits_glock", value: 361 }, { name: "total_shots_mac10", value: 862 }, { name: "total_hits_mac10", value: 261 }, { name: "total_shots_ump45", value: 1610 }, { name: "total_hits_ump45", value: 598 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { name, value }) => {
        var [, type, name] = name.split('_');
        r[name] = r[name] || { name };
        r[name][type] = value;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a loop would help a bit more then using regex to create a new object, not sure I've ever seen that before.

```js
var rawData = [ { "name": "total_kills_glock", "value": 70 }, { "name": "total_kills_mac10", "value": 39 }, { "name": "total_kills_ump45", "value": 136 }, { "name": "total_shots_glock", "value": 1262 }, { "name": "total_hits_glock", "value": 361 }, { "name": "total_shots_mac10", "value": 862 }, { "name": "total_hits_mac10", "value": 261 }, { "name": "total_shots_ump45", "value": 1610 }, { "name": "total_hits_ump45", "value": 598 } ];

var gunStats = [{
    "name": "glock",
    "kills": 0,
    "shots": 0,
    "hits": 0
},
{
    "name": "mac10",
    "kills": 0,
    "shots": 0,
    "hits": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "ump45",
    "kills": 0,
    "shots": 0,
    "hits": 0
  }
];

rawData.forEach((item)  => { 
    if (item.name.includes("glock")) {
        applyStatsToGun(item, "glock");
    }

    if (item.name.includes("mac10")) {
        applyStatsToGun(item, "mac10");
    }

    if (item.name.includes("ump45")) {
        applyStatsToGun(item, "ump45");
    }

});


function applyStatsToGun(item, gunName) {
    if (item.name.includes(gunName)) {

        if (item.name.includes("kills")) {
            var gun = gunStats.find((gun) => gun.name == gunName);
            gun.kills += item.value;
        }

        if (item.name.includes("shots")) {
            var gun = gunStats.find((gun) => gun.name == gunName);
            gun.shots += item.value;
        }

        if (item.name.includes("hits")) {
            var gun = gunStats.find((gun) => gun.name == gunName);
            gun.hits += item.value;
        }
    }
}


console.log(gunStats);
```

And if you don't know want to hard code the gun name strings, say there's hundreds first you'd want to get a list of all unique names iterating through the list to and parse the 3rd element in `name.split("_")[3]` then iterating through that list and applying the value instead of hard coding those values

Comment: Thank you, this works great too! This was similar to the initial code that I wrote, but couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. I'm learning so much from this code example that you wrote!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a pure functional solution, which combines a couple of useful techniques. Note, that you can re-use partial functions somewhere else in the code. Also, this way the calculation can be parallelized and distributed (although JavaScript is not there yet).

```js
 let raw = [
    {"name": "total_kills_glock", "value": 70},
    {"name": "total_kills_mac10", "value": 39},
    {"name": "total_kills_ump45", "value": 136},
    {"name": "total_shots_glock", "value": 1262},
    {"name": "total_hits_glock", "value": 361},
    {"name": "total_shots_mac10", "value": 862},
    {"name": "total_hits_mac10", "value": 261},
    {"name": "total_shots_ump45", "value": 1610},
    {"name": "total_hits_ump45", "value": 598}
];

//you can use any parsing technique here, including regexp
const parse = name => { 
    const a = name.split("_"); 
    return { key: a[2], metric: a[1] }
};

const groupBy = getKey => (rv, x) => {
    (rv[getKey(x)] = rv[getKey(x)] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
};

//converts [{key,metric,value},...] to {name:key, m1:v1, m2:v2,...} 
const recombine = arr => Object.assign({name: arr[0].key},
    ...Array.from(arr, ({key, metric, value}) => ({[metric]: value}) ));

const groupedByKey = raw
            .map( ({name, ...attrs}) => ({...parse(name), ...attrs}))
            .reduce(groupBy(x => x.key),{});

const result = Object.values(groupedByKey).map(recombine);
console.log(result);
```

I did not benchmark it, but I would not be surprised, if it performed better than Nick's solution with certain datasets. That said, it might not be as easy to maintain, depending on the team and skills.